# How we close the database when we open the db using getWritableDatabase();

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I am using the below code for create a database

```
public DataHelper(Context context) {  

           this.context = context;  

           OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);  

        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();  

           this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);  

        }
```

It is a constructor .
But when i use this in my activity as `DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(this);`
But i got the error is close the db.where i write the db close statemnet.I am follow the code which is provided in below limk.But i got error,Please give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance.
[link text](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)

Comment: It would be great if you could add the error that you get to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the database - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#close()
Close all opened database objects - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close()